# Plotting data points from txt file

Tags: matplotlib

I have tried every single solution suggested on the internet (including stackoverflow) and all of them report errors for me, even though I copy-paste the code as well as the file.
Lets say my file is asd.txt and it looks like this:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

where numbers are separated by space.

**1st solution from Stackoverflow:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("asd.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.split('\n')

x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
y = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title("Plot title...")    
ax1.set_xlabel('your x label..')
ax1.set_ylabel('your y label...')

ax1.plot(x,y, c='r', label='the data')

leg = ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

This gives an error :

```
File "C:/Users/cakodaqo/Documents/Python Scripts/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    y = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

**2nd solution:**

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
data = np.loadtxt('asd.txt')
pl.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], 'ro')
pl.xlabel('x')
pl.ylabel('y')
pl.xlim(0.0, 10.)
pl.show()
```

Error:

```
data = np.loadtxt('asd.txt')
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**3rd solution:**

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np

style.use('ggplot')

x,y = np.loadtxt('asd.txt',
                 unpack = True,
                 delimiter = ' ')
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.title('asd')
plt.ylabel('ihatepython')
plt.xlabel('ihatemyself')

plt.show()
```

Error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Ascii
```

Can someone PLEASE tell me the solution to all these problems? I tried changing my file , i tried changing delimiter, i copypasted the exact same files that are given online and somehow it works for everyone except for me :( If you dont know why i keep getting errors, then feel free to post your own solution (knowing my luck, that one will report an error too..). Thank you in advance

p.s. my actual data are float numbers, not integers and I would prefer to plot data as dots, without line connecting them

Comment: On the second solution: In `data = np.loadtxt(’asd.txt’)` you are not using the correct quotes. You need to use `'` or `"` instead of `’` (You can see that the code highlighting does not work properly). Then it should run. Does this solve the problem?

Also, your error message `data = np.loadtxt(’fakedata.txt’)`. This is not about the code you show above.

Comment: no, i wrote both correctly in the program. I only made a mistake in the post, i just edited it (tnx for pointing it out!)

Comment: The syntax error puzzle's me. Shouldn't be there. Could you just make sure that you copy-paste the exact example code that produces the error? As I understand it you retyped the code for stackoverflow in the current version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

On the second solution:

In `data = np.loadtxt(’asd.txt’)` you are not using the correct quotes. You need to use `'` or `"` instead of `’` (You can see that the code highlighting does not work properly).

Concerning the plotting you might want to consider using `scatter` instead of `plot` to get dots without a line.

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
data = np.loadtxt("asd.txt")
pl.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], 'ro')
pl.xlabel('x')
pl.ylabel('y')
pl.xlim(0.0, 10.)
pl.show()
```

Comment: as mentioned above, i wrote it correctly in the code (if i didnt, i wouldve had a different error). I made a mistake in the post

Answer (score 0):

You can import each column as an array with

```
import numpy as np

column1, column2 = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', unpack=True)
```

Edit: convert .txt.-File to UTF8 and try again-